# à bicyclette, en voiture

Tags: grammaire

Je me pose la question suivante : quelle est la règle concernant l'utilisation du **en** / **à** par rapport aux moyens de transport ? 
Exemple :

```
Une descente en skis ou à skis ?
une promenade en vélo ou à vélo ?
```

d'après l'académie française :

*L’Académie française recommande de réserver la préposition en aux véhicules ou aux moyens de transport dans lesquels on peut s’installer, prendre place. Dans les autres cas, c’est la préposition à qui sera employée.*

Je ne suis pas convaincu. Je ne vois aucune différence entre l'un et l'autre, tant d'un point de vue compréhension, que d'un point de vue grammaire.

Comment: Il n'est pas nécessaire de supprimer la question, même si c'est un double. Ça peut aider d'autres gens à trouver la question depuis des moteurs de recherche.